# Is there a way for Firebase Flutter apps to persist data across offline app restarts?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using a firebase animated list to show a list of items stored in firebase realtime database.

Now when I start the app(after the app is **killed**) in the **offline** state, the list does not load.

Is there a built-in method to store the data offline for this use case(provided by firebase)?  Or do I need to store in some offline database?

I have checked https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities but couldn't find this specific use case.

Related issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19271

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database or Firebase Cloud Firestore?

Comment: for FIrebase realtime database

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like `FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled`

```
  /// Attempts to sets the database persistence to [enabled].
  ///
  /// This property must be set before calling methods on database references
  /// and only needs to be called once per application. The returned [Future]
  /// will complete with `true` if the operation was successful or `false` if
  /// the persistence could not be set (because database references have
  /// already been created).
  ///
  /// The Firebase Database client will cache synchronized data and keep track
  /// of all writes you’ve initiated while your application is running. It
  /// seamlessly handles intermittent network connections and re-sends write
  /// operations when the network connection is restored.
  ///
  /// However by default your write operations and cached data are only stored
  /// in-memory and will be lost when your app restarts. By setting [enabled]
  /// to `true`, the data will be persisted to on-device (disk) storage and will
  /// thus be available again when the app is restarted (even when there is no
  /// network connectivity at that time).
  Future<bool> setPersistenceEnabled(bool enabled) async {
    // ...
  }
```

from [firebase_database/lib/src/firebase_database.dart](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/ae00731bfd7282ede0a50f94fdcfc1719c890ad5/packages/firebase_database/lib/src/firebase_database.dart)

Comment: if "restarted" is interpreted as the app goes in the background and not killed then yes, setPersistenceEnabled works, but my use case is the app is killed/terminated and then started(in offline state).

Comment: "persisted to on-device (disk)" is supposed to survive a terminated app. If it doesn't work please report a bug. Ensure you have tried with the latest plugin version and if possible also try with Flutter `dev` channel.

Comment: FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true); You may forgot .instance* before .setPersistenceEnabled.

Comment: This was changed a while ago. I haven't used it since.